# Absolute Galois group with unique closed non-open subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, fields, profinite-groups

Is there an absolute Galois group that is not a subgroup of $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ and that has one and only one closed non-open subgroup?

Comment: Yes, consider the extension of $\mathbf{F}_p$ with absolute Galois group $\mathbf{Z}_p$ (this is the union, inside a fixed algebraic closure, of $\mathbf{F}_{p^n}$ for all $n$ coprime to $p$).

Comment: (By the way a profinite abelian group with a single non-open closed subgroup is necessarily isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}_p$ for some prime $p$.)

Comment: @YCor is there an example where the field is not algebraic extension of a quasi-finite field?

Comment: You can make a similar example with $\mathbf{C}((t))$.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger but it is a quasi-finite field

Comment: Oops, sorry, it turns out I didn't know what "quasi-finite" is - I thought it meant "an algebraic extension over a finite field" :)

Comment: You could make the same example with the extension $\overline{F}_p((t))$ with absolute Galois group $\mathbf{Z}_\ell$ for some $\ell\neq p$. Strictly speaking, it's not an algebraic extension of a quasi-finite field.

Comment: Thank you YCor and Piotr Achinger for your comments. I modified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually this is purely a fact of profinite groups.

**Proposition.** *Let $G$ be an infinite profinite group in which every nontrivial closed subgroup is open. Then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}_p$ for some prime $p$.*

Proof. First, the case when $G$ is abelian. Then its Pontryagin dual is a discrete torsion abelian group, in which every proper subgroup is finite. It is standard (and easy) that this characterizes the Prüfer groups $C_{p^\infty}$ for $p$ prime, whose Pontryagin duals are the $\mathbf{Z}_p$.

Next, the general case. Let $x$ be a nontrivial element of $G$, and $A_x=\overline{\langle x\rangle}$ the closure of the subgroup generated by $x$. Then $A_x$ is open, so has finite index, hence is infinite. Hence this is an abelian group with the required condition, so is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}_p$.

Hence $G$ has a normal open subgroup $N$ isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}_p$; choose $N$ maximal with this property. Then $G/N$ is a $p$-group: indeed, otherwise, it has an element of prime order $\ell\neq p$; lift it to an element $x\in G$: then $A_x$  cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}_p$ (since it surjects onto $\mathbf{Z}/\ell\mathbf{Z}$) and cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}_q$ for any prime $q\neq p$ (since it intersects $\mathbf{Z}_p$ in a subgroup of finite index), contradiction with the abelian case.

Assuming by contradiction $N\neq G$, so the nontrivial $p$-group $G/N$ has a central subgroup of order $p$; let $H$ be its inverse image in $G$. So $N$ is normal of index $p$ in $H$. If $N$ is central in $H$, then since $H/N$ is cyclic, $H$ is abelian, hence isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}_p$ by the abelian case, contradicting the maximality of $N$. Fix $x$ not centralizing $H$. Since $A_x$ is infinite, $x^p$ is a nontrivial element of $N$. Hence the action by conjugation of $x$ on $N\simeq\mathbf{Z}_p$ has a nonzero fixed point. But any automorphism of the topological group $\mathbf{Z}_p$ is given by $x\mapsto sx$ for $s\in\mathbf{Z}_p^\times$, which fixes only zero. This yields a contradiction again. So $N=G$, hence $G\simeq\mathbf{Z}_p$.

Comment: I don't understand why if $A_x$ is open it must be infinite.

Comment: By assumption, G is infinite and A_x is open. By compactness, A_x has finite index in G and thus is also infinite.