# Field whose absolute Galois group is $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, galois-theory, fields

Let $L$ be a perfect field. Assume there is an algebraic closure $L\subset \overline{L}$ and a prime $p$ such that $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{L}/L)\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ as topological groups.

Is there a quasi-finite subfield $K\subset L$ such that $K\subset L$ is an algebraic extension?

Comment: Presumably $\mathbb Z_p$ here means the $p$-adic integers (as it should!), and not $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @LSpice it means the $p$-adic integers

Comment: Follow-up of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/388572/. Note that "quasi-finite" means a field whose absolute Galois group is isomorphic to $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}$ (or endowed with such an isomorphism, but this doesn't matter much here).